# Finitely many prime ideals lying over the same prime ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A \subseteq  B$ an extension of rings such that $B$ is an $A$-module finitely generated. Show that for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq A$ there is only a finite number of prime ideals $\mathfrak{q} \subseteq B$ such that $\mathfrak{q} \cap A = \mathfrak{p}$.